# Why does my Python codes give output with multiple lines?

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner and started my journey by solving some Code Forces problems.

I faced some problems when trying to write Python codes for this question: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A

Basically, the input row contains a string with numbers and '+', e.g. '3 + 2 + 1', and the codes must convert the string into a series in ascending order and print as output, e.g. output '1 + 2 + 3' from '3 + 2 + 1'.

This is my attempt:

```
lines = (sys.stdin.readlines())
answer = ''
arranged = []
intermediate = str((lines)[0]).split('+')
arranged += [intermediate[0]]
k = 1
i = 0
for k in range(1, len(intermediate)):
    while i < len(arranged) and intermediate[k] > arranged[i]:
        i += 1
    arranged[i:i] = [intermediate[k]]
for item in arranged:
    answer += item + '+'
print(answer[:-1])
```

When I ran the codes using custom test, it works: giving out '1 + 2 + 3' as output.

However, when I submitted my answer, the output was given as

```
1
+ 2 + 3
```

making my codes fail in first test.

Attached image to show what I meant:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: The `readlines` method returns a list of string (you know that already), but these string end with `\n`, the "newline" character. Use the `str.split()` method to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `readlines()`  captures a blank line (\n) that is attached to '1'.

Consider this solution, using 'strip' to remove the unwanted \n:

```
intermediate = str((lines)[0]).strip().split('+')
```

In this case a *debug print* would have been really useful.
By printing 'intermediate', the result is:

`['3', '2', '1\n']`

And you could have easily detected your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think `readlines()` captures a newline character `\n` that's "attached" to the `1` when you do the `split`. You can use the [strip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) function to remote leading and trailing whitespace characters.